# How can I see my newly added product(with all the fields added through adin) in Magento 1.9.2.4?

Tags: magento-1.9, product

For a product, I added all the fields, and the product doesn't show anywhere on front end Magento. These are the things I did:

-I added the product in admin
-Added fields:
-General -> Sku, Weight, Status(Enabled), Visibility(Catalog, Search)
-Prices -> Price, Tax Class
-Added images
-Inventory -> quantity is set
-Inventory -> Stock Availability = In Stock

Comment: try with `site-url/product-url.html`

Comment: I tried and I'm getting 404 error.

Comment: have you assigned website to the product

Comment: No, but where can I do that?

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic can you see `website` menu on left side at the time of editing product ? you can click on there and select checkbox & save it.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento I don't have "Websites" option there....

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic can you create some category and assign products to categories and check category url......

Comment: The product was already in default category. I created another category and put the product in it too. It's still not displayed.

Comment: `visibility- catalog/search` & `status - enabled` ?

Comment: @BabyinMagento yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, it seems that issue was at category level. The category wasn't set to display products. I resolved it by setting this for the category:
Display settings -> Display mode -> Static block and products
instead of
Display settings -> Display mode -> Static block only

Answer (score 0):

Edit you product and select **website** tab on left and select the website.
see image below

[image]

[image]

Comment: Somehow I don't have "Websites" in the admin menu. Only these:   General,  
Prices,  
Meta Information  ,
    Images,  
    Recurring Profile,
    Design,  
    Gift Options,  
    Inventory,  
    Categories,  
    Related Products,  
    Up-sells,  
    Cross-sells,  
    Product Reviews,  
    Product Tags,  
    Customers Tagged Product,  
    Custom Options.

Comment: in that case, check the followings: **Status :Enable**,  **Visibility :Catalog, Search**,  **Stock Availability:In Stock**

Comment: Everything is set correctly (Status=Enabled, Visibility=Catalog, Search, Stock Availability=In Stock).

Comment: the only thing I can think of now is, try reindexing, then clear cache.

Comment: It doesn't work. Thanks though.